# Prove that "Length of linearly independent list $\leq $ length of spanning list"

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, vector-spaces

In Sheldon Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right* Page 35, he gave a proof of "Length of linearly independent list <=length of spanning list"(see reference below) by using a process of adding a vector from independent list to the spanning list and then cancels a vector form the spanning list to form a new spanning list.

My question falls into the *Linear Dependence Lemma* part. *Linear Dependence Lemma* only tells us that we can remove some $v_j$ in the dependent list, but the proof he gives on the first picture says we can remove one of the $w's$, why not $u's$? How can he be so sure about that?

> My current understanding:
>
> Step 1: By the definition of *spanning list*, it's
>   easy to obtain that $u_1$ can be written as a linear combination of
>   the spanning list $w_1,...,w_n$ as $u_1=a_1w_1+...+a_nw_n$. Meanwhile,
>   the coefficients $a_1,...,a_n$ cannot all equals to $0$, or else
>   $u_1=0$, contradicting the presumption that $u_1,...,u_n$ is linearly
>   independent. Let $a_j\neq 0$, and thus we can rewrite
>   $u_1=a_1w_1+...+a_nw_n$ into
>   $w_j=-\frac{a_1}{a_j}w_1+...-\frac{a_{j-1}}{a_j}w_{j-1}-\frac{a_{j+1}}{a_j}w_{j+1}-...-\frac{a_n}{a_j}w_n+\frac{1}{a_j}u_1$,
>   implying $w_j\in span\{w_1,...,w_{j-1},w{j+1},...,w_n,u_1\}$, which is
>   why we can reduce some $w's$.
>
> Step $j$($j$>=$2$), also the coefficients of in the form of $a's$
>   in $u_j=a_1w_1+...+a_{n-j+1}w_{n-j+1}+b_1u_1+...+b_{j-1}u_{j-1}$
>   cannot all equals to zero, or else contradicts the presumption that
>   $u's$ are linearly independent. This is why we can always remove some
>   $w's$ in each step.

Please verify my understanding, this does not seem obvious to me and it took time for it to figure it out. However, I'm not so sure that I'm right, so please point out any mistakes and substitute my understanding of the question with a better explanation, thanks in advance.

Reference 1：[image: Proof of "Length of linearly independent list <=length of spanning list"]
Reference 2: *Linear Dependence Lemma*[image: Linear Dependence Lemma]

Comment: This is a rather long question and it takes a while to get to your question.  Perhaps it would be better to reorganize your question to highlight your specific issue earlier in the question.

Comment: Also, this question contains a picture of copyrighted material.  While this isn't a large amount of material and should be OK under fair use, be careful about posting copyrighted material.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I summarized Axler's proof in my own words to begin my question, maybe it can make people get to my question sooner. For the second issue, thank you for reminding me of the copyright issue, but I am a little confused, what I can do about it? Math is a public intellectual property to some extent, any advice for me to avoid getting into trouble?(I SO want to delete the reference, but for sake for clarity I didn't...)

Comment: @SheldonAxler: Please take a look at this. If you don't want me to post the material in your book just tell me, and I would remove them as soon as I see you reply. Anyway, a great book, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main thing to notice is the order of writing the list.

Your step 1 said we can remove $u_1$ is false. Note that in Linear Dependence Lemma, it said there exists a vector $v_j$ in the list so it belongs to span of all **previous** vectors $v_1, \ldots, v_{j-1}$. Notice all $v_1, \ldots, v_{j-1}$ are at the **left** of $v_j$ in the list $(v_1, \ldots, v_m)$.

Hence, if we write the list as 
$$u_1,w_1, \ldots, w_n$$
in this exact order, we can't remove $u_1$ because all $w_i$ are at the **right** of $u_1$ in the list. Hence, even if $u_1$ is linear combination of $w_1, \ldots,w_n$, $u_1$ is still not the corresponding $v_j$ satisfying Linear Dependence Lemma.

> Why can't we remove $u_i$?

All the steps give a general list $$u_1, \ldots, u_k,w_1, \ldots, w_l$$
that is linearly dependent. Linear Dependence Lemma said that in this this, there exists a vector $v$ so $v$ belongs to span of all previous vectors in the list. If this $v=u_i$ for some $i$ then $v \in \text{span}(u_1, \ldots, u_{i-1})$, which contradicts to condition that $(u_1, \ldots, u_k)$ is linearly independent. Thus, this $v$ must be different from any $u_i$. Thus, $v=w_i$ for some $i$. With this and condition (b) of the Linearly Dependent Lemma, we find that we can remove $v=w_i$. Thus, we can't remove $u_i$.

Comment: Well, order of list matters is what caused my problem. What I thought previously was to proove by contradiction that $u_i$ cannot be removed, but the process seems extremely redundant. By pointing out that the order of list in Linear Dependenr Lemma matters your explanation is terse yet clear, nice answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the above answer by @Tengu to be correct, but unsatisfying; it seemed like just a cheap trick to ensure that the $u_i$ came first, and therefore we must remove one of the $w_i$.

Allow me to present a different perspective. Since $u_1, w_1, \ldots, w_n$ was linearly dependent, then the linear combination $a_0u_1 + a_1w_1 + \ldots a_nw_n = 0$ had some $a_i \neq 0$. I claim there is some $w_i$ such that $a_i \neq 0$. To see this, if $a_0$ (corresponding to $u_1$) was nonzero, then certainly one of the $w_i$ must be nonzero, else the linear combination would not sum to $0$. (You might say, well what if $u_1$ is $0$? That cannot be possible - we assumed $u_1, \ldots, u_m$ was linearly independent.) On the other hand, if $a_0$ was zero, then the non-zero coefficient must have been one of the $w_i$, so we are done.

Now it just suffices to check that $u_1, w_1, \ldots, w_{i-1}, w_{i+1}, \ldots, w_n$ is a spanning list; that exercise is left to the reader.